# Add my custom css file using bootstrap 4 build tools

Tags: css, npm, bootstrap-4

I'm able to customize Bootstrap 4 variables using build tools according to 
[this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup)

My question is how can I generate another css file `MyCustomStyles.css` at the end of build process by running `npm build dist`? I made a `_MyCustomStyles.scss` and I wrote my codes but `npm build dist` only generate bootstrap files not my separate css file.I don't want the codes I wrote in `_MyCustomStyles.scss` get included inside bootstrap 4 files.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate new css files by adding required command to `package.json`

```
"css-compile": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap.scss dist/css/bootstrap.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-grid.scss dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/styles.scss dist/css/styles.css",
```